# Finding string in the textfield. Actionscript

Tags: string, actionscript, find, textfield

What is the best way to find a string (sentence of 1-3 lines) in the multiline textfield.

I have a textfield with a list of messages. In order to change every second messages color, i have to get the index where this message beggins.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

As i'm appending text, i use textfield.caretIndex to see the inserts. So i'm switching formats using this function:

```
                    if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    textfield.setTextFormat(colorFormat, lastCaret  , textfield.caretIndex);
                    formatStart = textfield.caretIndex;
                }
                else  { 
                    textfield.setTextFormat(textFormat, formatStart, textfield.caretIndex);
                    lastCaret = textfield.caretIndex;
                }
```